# vuetify 3 v-form isFormValid not working with reactive object composition api

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuetifyjs3

Trying to get a disabled button to switch to abled when all rules have been passed in a v-form.

heres the v-form:

```
<v-form ref="form" v-model="formDataState.isFormValid" data-cy="new-user-request-form-v-form"></v-form>
```

here is the reactive data object:

```
 const formDataState = reactive({
requestorValues: newRequest._value.requestorValues,
supervisorValues: newRequest._value.supervisorValues,
isFormValid: newRequest._value.isFormValid   });
```

inside of requestorValue is an object with `firstName: {rules: inputRules, label: labelValue, value:''}, lastName: {rules: inputRules, label: labelValue, value:''}` etc. I'm iterating on each object and creating the form and setting the value.

does the structure need to be in one seperate object like this?

```
{ 
    isFormValid:false,
    lastName: '',
    firstName: '', 
}
```

[playground Link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data does not have to be on the same object. What error you are seeing is most likely not coming from `reactive()` - I suspect it's the rules.

Here is a quick [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqNU8tu2zAQ/JUFUUAJYElIG6CAYLtuUfRU9FKgl8gHWlojbCiKICnFhqN/75KU40fcJL7YXO7OzM7Qdzv2Veus75AVbOqw0ZI7nJcKYNqn69Y00KdNW6OclazmjmfC/uFS1CWDSnJrqax5ekvHhe1WjXCZNtijcgEjoDjcuHQtUNYQa6efQEMwQunOgVAQaDqL5jv9KNmlmeIBt/uRTPIVyst9fboSqt53Xu5ZdJoYsQhb0m4dPiMfSjCDD2GtyxjzaX68Z9z92YCVU+C22uNGj8itohaWryR6cce+wmw2gzWXFks2/x26PTZBjIaOqOTyfLfzk8MA09wfQ2jU61MLh1JN86NI6WgrI7QDi67ToUU0ujUOdgZ55USPA6xN20BCDyKJEABVq6wLqZAL+8arXRQyyi6i5kks7sMrYOwCWAtj3S/eINVMJ9EWcNdzCbM50NeXTKhKdjXaq2STXMPTEyRkNhpQNAKPwt0DV7BJlhM4hFKA6qScQHgABSQ/PAd4kmQYlQBd/o/3W9tK5OqKjseMfiDQvk7207edcA2HgIZr7310e84mTAr1YLO/tlX0NwuelKyytmSkZpxi985pW+R5VSvqJFrRm0yhy5VucsrDifV28Sm7yW5uc3o8bl9LSZHNApqHWpZqIMYYbNpwfUYbLwL1GE7JCMmf39CwoLbcdMqJBtO6bUjMx+z2cxRzVM/QNunKtI/0CgilZKM/gccrfgfXm/sSxwvsnAh7NKlBVaNB896dzsZO9jq7e7FbSNtbPkxYnCPzo2q2/AeHxbrw) if you want to see that it works.

---

Note that the value returned from validation will be `null` when the form is valid and the event given in the [`validate-on`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#props-validate-on) prop (defaults to submit) has not occurred, so you have to specifically check for false:

```html
<v-btn type="submit" :disabled="formDataState.isFormValid === false">Submit</v-btn>
```

---

Also note that validation happens after the user interacted with the form. If you want to show error messages right away, you have to call the exposed [`validate()`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#exposed-validate) function manually on a template ref to the `v-form`:

```
// for <v-form ref="formRef">
const formRef = ref()
onMounted(() => formRef.value.validate())
```

Here is another [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Thanks for responding Moritz. I think you're on to something. I put a watcher on the isFormValid and it seems to only trigger on the rules, when I break the email rules etc. I'll show you my rules 
```export const formValidationRules = {
  inputRules: [
    value => !!value || 'This field is required',
    value => /^[\w,\s]+$/.test(value) || 'This field must only contain letters, numbers and empty spaces'
  ]}```

Comment: Rules look great, but what do you mean with validation being only triggered when you break the rules? Sounds like you want to validate immediately, not just when user input data or the form is submitted? If so, check the updated answer

Comment: Moritz this is awesome thank you so much, Im trying to get the trigger to true without having to do the onMounted validate, so basically the user comes in, sees that some fields are required. fills all of those out and then the button turns to active. without seeing vuetifys input errors all over the place.

Comment: actually after checking some things - it looks like it doesnt like hard set values. for some of the requestorValues I have values set into those inputs... I tested with your sand box and proved the form validation doesnt like it.

Comment: Hmm, I have added your rule into the last of the playgrounds, and it shows an error when I set an invalid preset. Can you share the sandbox where it is not working? I am happy to take a look

Comment: @MortizRingler I cant post the link as the url is too long

Comment: Also I am doing this with my submit button:



`<v-btn type="submit" :disabled="!data.isValid">Submit</v-btn>`

Comment: Hmm, either add the playground as an edit at the end of your question, or create a new one. As to `:disabled="!data.isValid"`, that's fine once you have called `validate()` on the template ref

Comment: Alrighty - I added the playground link at the end of my question, I dont think i can do an on mount validate() as I dont want the user seeing a bunch of red for all the fields they havent filled out.

Comment: Ah, ok. In general, this is not possible, you cannot validate the form but also not validate it. There is a [`resetValidation()`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#exposed-resetValidation] method you can use to undo validation, then you'd have to figure out how to combine the results from manual validation and subsequent automatic validation. But this is going to be fuzzy and it is beyond the scope of your initial question. Better ask a new one if you need help with that. Also note that disabling a button and not telling users why is not recommended afaik.

Comment: I agree and I really appreciate all your help. I didnt understand the confusion between automatic and manual validation. I generally prefer an on submit validate() but the user requirements are what they are. Once again thanks for all your help and if I'm ever in leipzig I'll buy you a beer.